# Find the number of occurrences of each word in a sentence in each target category

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have got something like this.

```
Sentence                                        Target
We regret to inform you about the result.        1
We are glad to inform you about the result.      2
We would like to inform you about the result.   3
We are surprised to see the result.              4
```

I want a word count that looks something like this

```
Word    Target 1    Target 2    Target 2    Target 4
Result     1           1            1           1
Inform     1           1            1           0
Surprised   0           0           0           1
```

... and so on. How do I do this?

Comment: You will get a much more friendly reception and much better help here if you show what code you have tried so far and describe what problems you were having with it. Without code, your question looks like a request for a free homework-writing service and many people don't like that.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I meant to ask if it was with pandas.

Comment: yes..its a pandas dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to

1. remove punctuation and lowercase the data
2. split on whitespace
3. `stack` to create a series
4. `groupby` on `Target`
5. find the `value_counts` of words for each target
6. `unstack` the result for your desired output

```
df.Sentence.str.replace('[^\w\s]', '')\
  .str.lower()\
  .str.split(expand=True)\
  .set_index(df.Target)\
  .stack()\
  .groupby(level=0)\
  .value_counts()\
  .unstack(0, fill_value=0)\
  .add_prefix('Target ')


Target     Target 1  Target 2  Target 3  Target 4
about             1         1         1         0
are               0         1         0         1
glad              0         1         0         0
inform            1         1         1         0
like              0         0         1         0
regret            1         0         0         0
result            1         1         1         1
see               0         0         0         1
surprised         0         0         0         1
the               1         1         1         1
to                1         1         1         1
we                1         1         1         1
would             0         0         1         0
you               1         1         1         0
```

Comment: All I have to say is that this is a very nice answer to a very bad question.